# Set EntityKey manually without accessing the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, entitykey

In my application (database-first) the primary keys are always created by client, not by the underlying database.

In Entity Framework v4 each `Entity` had it's `EntityKey` property that could be set manually.

However, I can't find it anymore in EF6?

Is there any specific reason why?

I don't want to call `ctx.SaveChanges()` only to have an `Entity's` key set as this means a call to the database.

I'm also wondering why `ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey` is gone?!

Answer (score 0):

If You're using POCO's - here's a sample how it could be done

```
public class ChronosItem 
{
    [Column, Key, Required, MaxLength(26), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get;  set; }
    ....
```

In case You cant adjust Your entities

override the "OnModelCreating" method on Your context.. like so..

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChronosItem >()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id)
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Comment: I'm using `database-first` approach. So, the `entities` are generated and I can't update each of them each time I update the database.

Comment: That's why Your EntitiesContext class is generated as 'Partial'. So there would be a place to put Your customisations that would not get overWriten when You update the model from DB.

Another thing - if EF thinks that the ID is autogenerated - Identity specification in SQL must be set to true (take a look at column properties in SQL)

Comment: In my case - if I generate the model from DB, the prop ID (for ChronosItem) has StoreGeneratedPattern = None